# how fill the dynamically created dropdownlist with data from database using ajax and web service in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-ajax

```
var index = 0;
function newitem() {

    index++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('newitem')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass" + index);
    var rdiv = 'removeclass' + index;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" id="ddlitem' + index + '"name="ddlitem"><option
value="">--select--</select> </div></div><div class="col-sm-3
nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text"
class="form-control" id="txtquantity' + index + '" 
name="txtquantity" value=""></div></div><div class="col-sm-3
nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text"
class="form-control" id="txtprice' + index + ' "name="txtprice"
disabled="disabled" value="" ></div></div><div class="col-sm-3
nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <input
type="text" class="form-control" id="txttotal' + index + '"
name="txttotal" disabled="disabled" value="" ><div
class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger"
type="button" onclick="remove_created_item(' + index + ');"> <span
class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
    objTo.appendChild(divtest);
};

function remove_created_item(idOfCreatedItem) {
    $('.removeclass' + idOfCreatedItem).remove();
}
```

Comment: Clear your question first

Comment: Elaborate your question, use the body for adding details, not cramming it all in the subject and leaving the body with just the code. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but I think I understand what you are doing.

After the `objTo.appendChild(divtest);` which inserts your `select` dropdown into the page, do your Ajax call to the API:

```
var copyOfIndex = index;
$.get( "/api/whatever", function( data ) {
 $( "#ddlitem" + copyOfIndex ).html( data ); // data => can be the html containing all the <options> 
 alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

not sure how your code is initialized above, but you should use a copy of your index (`copyOfIndex` here) to make sure the ajax call doesn't use an outdated value for `index` when the ajax call completes.

Also, looks like you need to close your  before you insert the element in the DOM via `objTo.appendChild(divtest);`